# How to remove this frame in MS Teams chat, when I copy from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, microsoft-teams

[image]

Sorry that I even do not know what the name of this frame is. It will appear when I copy something from IntelliJ. I tried to clear all formatting, quote and remove tables, but none of them was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Format button then choose the **paragraph** option as shown in the image below to remove that frame.

[image: Teams]